# Twilio capability token gets longer and longer

Tags: java, twilio

I'm using Twilio's [Java helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java) to generate a capability token for my Angular app to use to make calls from the browser. Here's the code:

```
public class CapabilityToken {
  private TwilioCapability capability;

  public String get(String applicationSid) {
    capability.allowClientOutgoing(applicationSid);
    try {
      String token = capability.generateToken();
      // logging happens here
      return token;
    } catch (DomainException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

On the Angular side, we make a call to our API to fetch a new token and then use that to initialize the device.

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token, {debug: true});
```

I noticed in [the logs](http://pastebin.com/YzRkrL9Z) that the token gets longer and longer as repeated calls are made to generate this token.

The [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens#token-expiration) recommends generating a token every time a new phone call is made, but when I tried that, the token quickly became unusable because it was too long. So now I'm just fetching the token on page load, but the token still gets really long too quickly.

Why is this happening and where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The way you have set your `CapabilityToken` class up is the issue here. You seem to be storing a capability token as a class level variable and every time you call `get` on the class you add another outgoing client permission to it. That's why it is increasing in size each time. Instead, you should generate a new `TwilioCapability` each time, like so:

```
public class CapabilityToken {
  public String get(String applicationSid) {
    TwilioCapability capability = new TwilioCapability(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    capability.allowClientOutgoing(applicationSid);
    try {
      String token = capability.generateToken();
      // logging happens here
      return token;
    } catch (DomainException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you! Question: would it be okay if I set the client permission once as well? Or do I need to create a new TwilioCapability every time? (Reason I'm asking is because I need to decrypt the account SID and auth token and I would prefer to do that once.)

Comment: You need a new capability each time. But why not only decrypt the account SID and auth token once when your application is loaded, then use them each time to generate the capability token?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm doing now. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well!